# Ubuntu 20.04 top bar text disappearing - system starts lagging a lot

Tags: gnome, 20.04, top-bar

I would like to know if anyone has a clue about what may be causing my top bar + sidebar text disappearing after longer uptime (few hours).
[image: Looks like this.]

System also becomes very laggy, display (except of cursor) freezes for a whole second about every 30 seconds when doing anything (typing this, watching video, not even anything intensive).

Freezing is resolved by putting pc to sleep, disappearing text is not, for that I have to reboot.

I am on a laptop (Dell XPS13, i7-8550u) if some drivers could cause an issue.
I was also upgrading from Ubuntu 19.10.

Does anyone know what may cause this issue? Or where to start with troubleshooting?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 using the Gnome Desktop (not Unity Desktop) has know issues with memory leaks. Use `free -h` to watch free memory through out your session and see if problem correlate to low memory.

Comment: I’ll take a look into it, but so far I haven’t noticed low memory problems as I watch my memory occasionally, it doesn’t usually go above what is reasonable and I’m sure l’m not running out of memory. When not doing anything memory intensive except web browser my use is around 5-8GB/16, gnome-shell process itself never going higher than few hundred MB.

Comment: A google search reveals lots of instances of disappearing text but all results are for older problems. I'm not sure you'll find an answer there but you could try.

Comment: next time try: `Alt+F2` and then type `r` and confirm with enter - this will restart gnome-shell -- perhaps this helps avoiding restarts

Comment: pls disable all extensions, and check if this re-occurs - if not seperatly enable one after the other

Comment: I have the same issue and have disabled all GNOME extensions as a troubleshooting step. The issue persists. I also have a dell XPS 13. However, I do not have the input lag issue. I can confirm that restarting gnome-shell does fix the issue but is just a workaround.

Comment: I have the same problem - no lag etc. Any ideas on fixes?

Comment: The `r` worked! In my case, this problem was seen immediately after boot, seen after upgrading to a large monitor. OS is inside virtual box. Funnily enough the Alt+F2 screen showed only **some** letters: "C mm" instead of "Run a Command". Crazy how that can happen!