# Ubuntu 20 - Gnome text randomly disappears

Tags: gnome

I have an issue with Gnome and Ubuntu 20. In particular, top bar text and drop-down menus characters randomly disappear, in a similar way to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249438/ubuntu-20-04-top-bar-text-disappearing-system-starts-lagging-a-lot). The only fix I found is to reboot. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

P.S. My software is up to date.

EDIT: Info about my computer and graphics card:

```
sudo lshw -C video

  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:131 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107 [GeForce 940MX]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:134 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4080000-a40fffff
```

Comment: Any gnome-shell extension ?

Comment: Add information about your computer and graphics card (edit your post for this)

Comment: not an solution, but perhaps an better solution than rebooting: press `Alt+F2`then type `r` and confirm with enter -- this restarts Gnome-Shell

Comment: @vanadium Are there any preinstalled extensions I should be aware of? I haven't installed any.

Answer (score 20):

Had the same issue.  Reboot did not fix.  db429's suggestion of restarting Gnome-Shell worked, though not instantly.  I noticed everything (header, desktop icon text) back after a few minutes, but as noted in comments it was just a long few seconds.

Steps: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `r`, hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, even if you can't see what it says when you do so.

Comment: db429's solution works for me too. Everything is back to normal in a few seconds on my machine.

Comment: Happened again and checked - back in 7 seconds.  Long enough that I missed it changing after.  Thanks again all.

Comment: In 20.04, alt+F2+r works, but after upgrade to 22.04, this does not work. Still try to find other solution

Comment: I'm 90% sure I've used it successfully on 22.04, but it's also been happening a lot less in it.